# I am trying to do a simple connection with XAMPP and sql server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When ever I try to enter data or connect to the database, I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> mysql_pconnect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\smstrail\admin\lib\dbcon.php:8
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\smstrail\header.php(2): dbcon() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\smstrail\index.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
>
> ## 2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\smstrail\admin\lib\dbcon.php on line 8

Example of line 8:

```
@mysql_pconnect($host,$user,$pass);
```

Comment: use `mysql_pconnect` is not a function. replace it with `mysqli_connect`. Add complete code for that file for more detail

Comment: **This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.**   [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)

Comment: Are you trying to connect to SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysql_pconnect` is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. You should either use 
`mysqli_connect` or make a connection using PDO. Check out the documentation for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php